# Automatic install of a Java app that requires multiple key presses in Bash

Tags: java, linux, bash, cloud

guys, I am trying to install a `.jar` app with bash, I am running the code as so:

```
java -jar someApp.jar -console
```

The problem is:

1. I need to press `1` to start installation
2. Then I need to press `Enter` twenty-two times to accept license agreement ( I know ridiculous)
3. Then I need to press `1` again.

I tried using expect but It's hard to do because the license agreement has boatloads of text...

I tried piping multiple commands to the script like this:

```
echo '1', echo -ne "/n" | java -jar servoy_installer.jar -console
```

But no luck,

Thanks,

Comment: I bet there's a reason they want you to press [enter] that often (they want you to read the license).

Comment: yeah tell me about it :p @Thomas

Comment: @Raja: Just a blind guess, `printf "1" ; printf '\n%.0s' {1..22}; printf "1" | java -jar servoy_installer.jar -console`? worth trying?

Comment: @GhostCat oh man I learnt a lot since this question. To be honest I followed the last step which was to contact them and talk to them about it. They added an automated install option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools like `expect`; for example the various python versions of that, like [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/doc/)

Basically `expect` scripts allow you to code such kind of "interactions" (as long as the program you are dealing with is reading from *stdin* and writing to *stdout*).

In other words: you should check out in what way your preferred scripting language supports "expect" like behavior; and then you can create some scripting to automate such things.

But as indicated within the comments: depending on the underlying licence, doing so might be a **violation** of the licence terms of the software you are using. A "workaround" might be to have **your** installer put up those licence statements, to ensure that *somehow* the user is notified about them!